# net use and Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, permissions, windows-8.1, printer, port

I have a script that in run by some application. The script adds a shared printer to lpt1 port, then sends a file to it so it get printed then removes the printer from the port:

Everything works fine until it is installed on a computer with recent **Windows 8.1** system:

[image]

The message in English means: **The password for [shared printer name] is incorrect, enter user name for [computer name]**

It works okay when I run it manually as administrator but I'm afraid I won't be always able to do it. I'd like it to be run in a script by a program which is used by a standard user.

When I googled for "windows 8 + net use" I found that people are having various problems with it but unfortunately not any answer for my issue.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: What I need would be:

- a syntax for a command something like below, which would do the job:

  net use lpt1: \hostname\printer name -user:admin -password:xyz123
- a way to change computer configuration so it didn't ask for passwords.

**EDIT 2:**
After some experimenting I believe now it's not Windows 8 specific problem, it was just a coincidence. I made tests on another computer with Windows 8 and there wasn't such an issue. It didn't ask me for any passwords there and happily executed the command.

I tried some solutions hinted here, checked password protected sharing (it was off),
 tried running it as some user (doesn't help, any existing user and password won't work)

Still it works if I right click on CMD icon and select "Run as Administrator". Strange

Then I found this link, seems very similar to my problem
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b33638c8-1032-4775-82e2-21f457cd0b70/net-use-lpt-access-denied

I'll be trying suggestions from there - disabling lpt in device manager, trying all lpt ports possible, giving rights to some folders etc.

I've got a question now - I'm new to SuperUser, what should I do with the bounty now?

Comment: What does running as an administrator entail? Is it running with a different user? The issue here is evident: The current user has no right to the share.

Comment: You are right, Captain Obvious. He has no right to do it. In Windows XP any user could do it, in Windows 7 any user could do it, now he can't do it and I'm asking for a way to deal with it

Comment: If you add the right credentials, as the standard user, is it working? Will there be many users using the script or just one?

Comment: Yes yes, and here I was thinking you need help. My bad. Is this an Active Directory environment? Is there a user with the same name but different password on the `MAGAZYN` server? What happens if you use the "Guest" user on the `net use` command line?

Comment: Dumb question, why not use Group Policy ?

Comment: This sounds like a UAC (User Account Control) problem. UAC has been around since Windows Vista. You can try disabling it in Control Panel, or bypassing it by having it run from a Windows Service (eg. Task Scheduler).

Answer (score 1):

Run it as a Scheduled Task. You can program the password so it is not part of a script and you can run it on logon/logoff.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NET USE option '/savecred' the first time you connect to the printer manually.

Afterwards, this option will store the password and user information for use next time you connect using the option '/persistent:yes'

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows 7, Microsoft now requires specifying the password for using a share.
This was not required in XP.

The full syntax of the [net use](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg651155.aspx) command is :

```
net use lpt1: \\servername\printer /user:username password
```

You could add to the command the user-name and password for an administrator on MAGAZYN.
You could also try [turning off Password protected sharing](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/185429-password-protected-sharing-turn-off-windows-7-a.html) in the server.

If you don't want to put a clear-text password in a script, perhaps the answer by @BryanC
can help you specify it only once.

Comment: The one deciding whether the implicit authentication is valid is the server. This has nothing to do with the client’s Windows version.

Comment: @DanielB: Microsoft did make a big change to the network protocol on 7. The differences are enough to cause difficulties in having both XP and 7 or later on the same network.

Comment: Yes they did. However, most of that won’t affect anything when the server stays the same. From what I understand, that is the case at the OP’s office.

Comment: @DanielB: If the OP has Server 2003 or XP as server, he's certainly going to have troubles with a Windows 8.1 client.